# Is it possible to continue flying without electric power?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airbus, boeing, aircraft-failure

To be specific with the question, I would like to know if if it is possible to continue flying in the event of total loss of electrical power. Obviously, I know this entails the shutting down of engines which would discontinue the ouput of thrust, therefor disabling the aircraft's ability to safely climb and maintain altitude. So, in technical terms, the aircraft would therefor be gliding rather than flying, but I would still like to know if its possible to do so without any power (primary or auxiliary/emergency, although having absolutely 0 power is extremely unlikely).

Here is my question: **Is is possible to control an aircraft with absolutely zero electricity midflight?** I also understand that smaller planes can be controlled purely by the hydraulics systems, but does that also apply to larger aicraft such as the Boeing 747, Airbus 320, etc.?

Comment: Answers vary widely depending on aircraft so you will need to be more specific.  Also, what leads you to believe that you would need to shut the engines down?

Comment: [Gimli glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimli_Glider) is a famous case of in-flight loss of electric power after fuel exhaustion, with a wind turbine used as a last resort generator.